# Derivative of $ \sqrt x + sinx $

Tags: derivatives

Please help me find out derivative of  $\sqrt x + \sin x$. This is to be solved using first principle of derivatives only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dx} \sqrt x + \sin x
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {(\sqrt{x+h}+\sin(x+h)) - (\sqrt x+\sin x)} {h} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x} h + \frac {\sin(x+h)-\sin x} h \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x) (\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)} {h (\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)} + \frac {2\cos(x+h/2)\sin(h/2)} h \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {(x+h) - x} {h (\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)} + \cos(x+h/2) \frac {\sin(h/2)} {h/2} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac h {h (\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)} + \cos(x+h/2) \frac {\sin(h/2)} {h/2} \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x} + \cos(x+h/2) \frac {\sin(h/2)} {h/2} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}+\sqrt x} + \cos(x) \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 1 {2\sqrt{x}} + \cos(x) \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I appreciate your help but can you please solve it again with only x under square root plus sinx. I would really appreciate that. I cannot upload photo since im new over here.